# Rails video uploading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I've searched around for different uploading options for rails and video and Paperclip seems to be pretty good, but are there any others people would recommend, it should have good tutorials and docs because i can't really find any great paperclip docs involving uploading video content.

Comment: you  can use rheaton carrierwave-video gem to upload video

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We got Paperclip working with video a while back

---

**Systems**

You'll have the same ambiguity whether you use [CarrierWave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) or [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) (Rails' two main "attachment" handlers)

Any upload system only handles the transfer of file data between your PC, your Rails app & your db. Each of them (from my understanding). E.G Paperclip only creates an `ActiveRecord` object from your file, saves the data to your server's `public` dir & creates a record in your db

---

**Code**

The question of video is one of using the right *processor*, rather than the right uploader:

```
#app/models/attachment.rb
has_attached_file :attachment,
    styles: lambda { |a| a.instance.is_image? ? {:small => "x200>", :medium => "x300>", :large => "x400>"}  : {:thumb => { :geometry => "100x100#", :format => 'jpg', :time => 10}, :medium => { :geometry => "300x300#", :format => 'jpg', :time => 10}}},
    processors: lambda { |a| a.is_video? ? [ :ffmpeg ] : [ :thumbnail ] }
```

---

**Extra**

You'll need to use a video processor such as [ffmpeg for Paperclip](https://github.com/owahab/paperclip-ffmpeg):

```
#GemFile
gem "paperclip-ffmpeg", "~> 1.0.1"
```

You may have to [install ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) on your system to get the processor to work locally (Heroku has ffmpeg). This will allow you to use the [`video_tag` helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-video_tag):

```
<%= video_tag(@model.attachment.url) %>
```

There's a good tutorial about [using ffmpeg with Paperclip here](http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2009/2/22/video-thumbnails-with-ffmpeg-and-paperclip)
And [another tutorial here](http://torsd.wordpress.com/2010/01/28/video-upload-with-paperclip/)

Comment: Gem ffmpeg for Paperclip is deprecated. New gem for same purpose here: https://github.com/ruby-av/paperclip-av-transcoder

Comment: undefined method `instance' for #<MeasurementImage:0x00000003c8f818>

Comment: If you write a question & send the link, I will make an answer for you

Answer (score 0):

With rails Carrierwave and Paperclip are the best attachment handlers. Now
for all kinds of file upload like images, videos, other raw files etc. you can use **Cloudinary** with carrierwave. See this 
http://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_carrierwave