# rails uploading file to Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to upload files directly to AmazonS3 from my Rails application. config looks like this at the moment:

**Gemfile**

gem "paperclip"

gem 'aws-sdk'

**In config/application.rb**

```
# Amazon S3 configuration for paperclip
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_host_name => 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'
}
```

**Model - movie.rb**

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base

   # add File to Movie association on column mo
   has_attached_file :movie,
                :storage => :s3,
                :bucket => '--',
                :s3_credentials => {
                    :bucket => '---',
                    :access_key_id => '---',
                    :secret_access_key => '---'
                }

  # validdates the file type
  validates_attachment_content_type :movie, :content_type => /\Avideo\/.*\Z/

end
```

**Controller movies_controller.rb**

```
class MoviesController < ActionController::Base

  layout "application"

  # Method to add a new Movie
  def addMovie

    if request.post?
      #@movie = Movie.new(movies_params)
      @movie = Movie.new(params[:movie])
      if @movie.save
        flash[:notice] = t("flash.moveuploadstarted")
        redirect_to :addMovie
      end
    else
      @movie = Movie.new
    end
  end


  private

   def movies_params
    params.require(:movie).permit(:movietitle, :movieprice, :locked,    :moviedescription, :currency, :language)
  end

end
```

Database looks like this:
[image]

When I fill my form and send the movie the browser starts to upload the movie the persentage is shown on left bottom corner. But when 100% are reached the movie isn't stored to Amazon S3 and DB is empty, but no errors or so....

What could be the problem? .

UPDATE:

upload form has this input file for the video

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label><%= f.label :movie %></label>
      <%= f.file_field :movie, :class => "form-control", :placeholder => :movie %>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code that goes if you use carrierwave, but should be the same for paperpclip (by the way, carrierwave is the standard and recommended)

Note that it should be in the config initializers file

```
config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb

if Rails.env.production?
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.fog_credentials = {
      # Configuration for Amazon S3
      :provider              => 'AWS',
      :aws_access_key_id     => ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY'],
      :aws_secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET_KEY']
    }
    config.fog_directory     =  ENV['S3_BUCKET']
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried it this way: https://u.osu.edu/hasnan.1/2014/03/13/rails-4-upload-image-to-s3-using-fog-and-carrierwave/ but it dosn't work

Comment: here is my carrierwave code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35983943/rails-upload-files-to-amazon-s3-with-carrierwave-and-fog

Answer (score 1):

For giggles can you try hard doing the bucket name, access key and secret key in to the application.rb file? I'm wondering if the bucket and other info need to be in the config file

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried printing the params[:movie] to the console?

```
puts params[:movie]
```

It's looks like you're getting the movie hash from the parameters rather than the value from a field inside that hash. I would suggest that you use a field name for saving the video file, movie_video for example.

```
 class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base

       # add File to Movie association on column mo
       has_attached_file :movie_video,
                    :storage => :s3,
                    :bucket => '--',
                    :s3_credentials => {
                        :bucket => '---',
                        :access_key_id => '---',
                        :secret_access_key => '---'
                    }

      # validdates the file type
      validates_attachment_content_type :movie_video, :content_type => /\Avideo\/.*\Z/

end
```

Comment: have added the file_input above

Comment: have you tried to output the params in the controller? Generally rails controller actions expect to process a hash which basically represents an instance of the respecttive model, in this case your Movie model is represented by the :movie hash, and actions in the MovieController acts upon that Movie. Because there is no field in your model called :movie the value can't be written anywhere I'd say.

Comment: tried it with carrierwave now .. but same issues ... nothing done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35983943/rails-upload-files-to-amazon-s3-with-carrierwave-and-fog

Comment: There might be something useful that you can find in the logs as to what is going on, on the server. Also [this answer may help you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21496936/6058530).

Comment: The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.

what can I do

Comment: And now paperclip starts uploading ... I can see it in console but it don't do it ... its a small image with about 1MB but it dosn't geht to amazon ... loop

Comment: looks to be at least trying to interact with AWS, however not being authorised. Some further detail [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1691) from people who looks to have had the same issue.