# Rails: Paperclip produces different results for similar videos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, ffmpeg, paperclip

I am using the [Paperclip Gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) to handle video uploads on my Rails app. I've followed the instructions in a few [other stackoverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21491643/rails-video-uploading) and external tutorials to get video uploads working. However, currently there is a strange glitch with the system that I don't understand.

When uploading two different videos, the app will be able to show a thumbnail and no video for one upload, and no thumbnail but video for another one.

Both videos use the same codecs, are around the same length, but are a bit different in their dimensions & file size.

[image: the video details]

When I upload them, `test1` has a thumbnail, but my browser will not load the video file. It exists in my file system but Chrome will not play it.

The opposite happens for `test2`. Its thumbnail in my file system is zero bytes, but the video loads fine in my browser.

Here are the paperclip upload parameters for my object:

```
has_attached_file :video, :styles => {
    :medium => { :format => 'mp4' },
    :thumb => { :geometry => "500x500#", :format => 'jpg', :time => 10 }
  }, :processors => [:transcoder]
validates_attachment_presence :video
validates_attachment :video, content_type: { content_type: ["video/mp4", "video/mov", "video/wav", "video/wmv"] }
```

### [I've created a Github repo with an example app that reproduces the issue, at least on my system.](https://github.com/skwh/Paperclip-video-example)

Comment: can you upload the two samples somewhere?

Comment: @aergistal [test1.mp4](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10944218/test1.mp4) and [test2.mp4](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10944218/test2.mp4)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in: `:time => 10` parameter

Change it on: `:time => 1`

This change means: create screenshot on `1`st second instead of `10`th second. Because the second movie has only 10 second length, during the first movie has 12 seconds length. Thus the first movie has screenshot, and second don't and uses previous one.

Wish it helped you!

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Your solution works perfectly, however it only addresses half of my issue. Do you have any idea why the first video does not load?

Comment: @Polyov it loads well. You can check it by adding `p video.attachment.path` in the file and run it https://gist.github.com/itsNikolay/9eeb4b7217cd894c24c825fa6a2c8dba

Comment: `video.attachment.path` returns the correct path, but the video still does not play in my browser, even if i navigate to that path.

Comment: @Polyov does it play well in video player on your computer (not in browser)

Comment: yes, it plays fine when i use Finder (the filesystem) to access it.

Comment: @Polyov what's output in browser when you visit a video url?

Comment: If i go to, for example, `test2.mp4`, using the link that is generated by devise, i get the default chrome video player, and can watch the video.

Comment: @Polyov I succesfully onened both videos in my Crome browser. It looks like everything OK with codecs

Comment: @Polyov If you want you can share on Github minimal application where you can reproduce this issue, that I can run it.

Comment: I have added a link at the bottom of my question. I'll award you the bounty because you've solved half the problem when the bounty period expired.

Comment: @Polyov thank you! I'll take a look it after my work

Comment: @Polyov I couldn't reproduce the issue. It's look like everything works well in Google Chrome v. 54 https://youtu.be/HJDsR1nbG4g

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. It must be an issue singular to my system, then.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to play both files in multiple browsers without issue.

However, the reasons why **test1.mp4** might not (seem) to work are:

1. `test1.mp4` has the `moov` atom at the end of the file:

   ```
   AtomicParsley test1.mp4 -T
   Atom ftyp @ 0 of size: 32, ends @ 32
   Atom free @ 32 of size: 8, ends @ 40
   Atom mdat @ 40 of size: 1310866, ends @ 1310906
   Atom moov @ 1310906 of size: 9926, ends @ 1320832
   ```

   This means the browser must fully download the file before it can play it. If you're on a slow connection it might take a while and appear like it's not working.

   `test2.mp4` has the `moov` atom at the beginning of the file meaning it can be played back before the download finishes:

   ```
    AtomicParsley test2.mp4 -T
    Atom ftyp @ 0 of size: 32, ends @ 32
    Atom moov @ 32 of size: 7464, ends @ 7496
   ```

   You can move the `moov` atom to the beginning of the file using the `ffmpeg` `movflags faststart` option or with the `qt-faststart` tool.

   It shouldn't be an issue if you're using your local file system, so see below.
2. `test1.mp4` uses the `Main` `H.264` profile while `test2.mp4` uses the `Constrained Baseline` profile. This can be an issue on some mobile devices as the `Baseline` profile has the most support. However it shouldn't be an issue with newer devices.

   You could try to re-encode it with the `Baseline` profile to see if this is the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. The videos, using my dropbox links above, both play fine for me in the browser. the problem just comes when i'm trying to watch `file1.mp4` on my filesystem, using the link that rails comes up with. Secondly I've tried re-encoding `test1.mp4` to use `Baseline` using Handbrake, and there was no difference when I uploaded it using my app.

Answer (score 0):

Please do follow this link `https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation`

and i think validation for video can be done in this way:

`validates_attachment :video, :presence => true`

rather than doing with presence and again without it.

**For image i followed :**

`validates_attachment :attachment, content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"] }`

Hope this will work for you :-)